# Able to choose future date when setting max date in datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm targeting for and building with API level 21, using AppCompat v21.

It gives me a nicely looking new date picker, which has the unexpected property of allowing me to choose a future date when [max date](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long)) has been set using

```
datePicker.setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
```

The future dates are greyed out, but I can still choose any one of them. Is that a bug? Am I doing it wrong? Is there a way to prevent the user from being able to pick a future date in the date picker?

The old Holo date picker did not allow picking a future date when setting a maximum date.

**UPDATE:**

While it is not working properly on my Nexus 4 running stock 5.0, it is working properly on my Nexus 6 running stock Android 5.1.1. Perhaps it was a bug in Android 5.0 and it was fixed in 5.1? Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So to answer my own question:

I've looked at the Android source of `DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java` at grepcode, specifically at `public void setMaxDate(long maxDate)` for both Android versions [5.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java#DatePickerCalendarDelegate.setMaxDate%28long%29) and [5.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/widget/DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java#DatePickerCalendarDelegate.setMaxDate%28long%29).

What's new in 5.1 in `setMaxDate()` is that

`mDayPickerView.goTo(getSelectedDay(), false, true, true);`

has been changed to:

`mDayPickerView.setMaxDate(maxDate);`

It seems they fixed it there, which corresponds with my observation that it works as expected in 5.1 but not in 5.0.

And so it seems we're stuck with dealing with the fact that it doesn't work properly in Android 5.0 (days after max date are greyed out but can still be chosen).

Comment: so what do we do ?

Comment: What I did was simply ignore the selected date if the user chose a date in the future and show an error message (snackbar or toast). Another solution could also be to use another datepicker, perhaps https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: In onDateSet() we can put a check like this 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (calendar.getTime().after(calendar1.getTime())) {
           Toast.makeToast(getApplicationContext,"Please select a valid date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

Answer (score 2):

**I am using this and its working correctly**

Call this function to open date picker

```
public void openDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dpd.show();
    }
```

Here is the **mDateSetListener**

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            date.setText(dayOfMonth + " / " + (monthOfYear + 1) + " / " + year); // Here date is a TextView to display date
            date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a method in which u can pass the value of the date entered by the user and compare it for example to the current date , if it's a future date u can reset the value of date used to  a specific one (for example the current date) and show a toast to inform him.

Comment: Thanks, I realize I can do that, but I didn't have to do so before (with the old date picker), and I find it odd that I'd have to that now. I'd like to know if i can get the date picker to not allow picking future dates (and if not, I'd like to know if the Android team has done this on purpose, or if it's a bug)

Answer (score -2):

you can work around it on your CSS by finding the right element (with a "disabled" class) and setting a pointer events to none.`

```
.bs-datepicker-body table td.disabled {
      pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: The question is about Android framework coding, not CSS