# How to set a date range in android calendar view?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, user-experience, android-calendar

I'm trying to set the calendar to display a range of days, for example from 1/1 to 5/1 as the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxFBH.png)

Please tell me how to do it. I've been trying many things like setmin and setmax but I think they're not the answer.

Comment: Are you using a [Material date picker](https://material.io/components/date-pickers) ? If so,  here's an [example](https://medium.com/@maithilijoshi94/new-material-date-range-picker-in-android-abd050bfc86d)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004398/restrict-range-in-android-datepicker-custom-dialog/62080184#62080184