# DatePickerDialog Convert into Date Picker Range Java Android

Tags: java, android, xml, date

I have used DatePicker Dialog but I want to use date range picker. Here is my code I have tried:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener returndate =new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
        updateLabel();
    }

    private void updateLabel() {
        String myFormat="yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        dpDate.setText(dateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
};

dpDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),R.style.DialogTheme,depdate,myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

How can I change to date range picker system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict Range in Android DatePicker Custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004398/restrict-range-in-android-datepicker-custom-dialog)

Comment: I didn't use material Date picker