# setMaxDate() not working perfectly on Lollipop 5.0.1 android and need proper solution

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Even after applying `setMaxDate()` to datepicker, I am still able to select the disabled dates on lollipop 5.0.1. The code is working fine for all other versions of android except for lollipop 5.0.1.

Here after restricting the dates by setting `setMaxDate()`, no user should be able to select disabled dates. How can I achieve this programmatically for `DatePicker`?

I have tried the below code:-

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(myContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Also I tried below solutions but these don't seem to work:-

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and

```
Calendar maxCal = Calendar.getInstance();
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

and

```
Date maxDate = new Date();
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
```

Please provide solution which is working for lollipop to `setMaxDate()`.

Or if you have any other answer, please try to include official quote and resources or links (like android developer site) if you know with brief details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you mention the device manufacturer name?

Comment: It´s maybe related to System.currentTimeInMillis() and it´s implementation. Have You tried with Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() ?

Comment: @RahulKhurana My phone is SAMSUNG.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I don't think so its long value. Moreover, I have mention that it is working fine in other version.

Comment: If you have time and possible, try and check it and give solution if you find it. BTW, thanks.

Comment: in the API it´s stated out the System.currentTimeInMillis() **value depends on the underlying operating system and may be large** .....I don´t think that it is much larger, but I don´t know how exact you want to be. Anyway, it´s not pain to try Calendar, maybe it works...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Sorry Bro.. Not success even in Calendar.

Comment: lollipop 5.0 datepickerdialog is buggy: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37018603 from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33051501/2657100

Comment: **Don't try getting this to work.** `DatePicker` will vary for every device and Android version, some show the dates as disabled, while some let you still select them, and others ignore those settings alltogether. Make sure to check the returned values, and / or switch to some other library (google / github search). Source: Wasted enough time on this.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanks for suggestion and answer. If you know library which will work as per my question then please mention that.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak If you know official document of what you are saying, please mention that also which will be very helpful to me. I think Then it will be very truly, correct and official answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have found one library **`wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker`** for datePicker and it is **working perfectly** in **lollipop 5.0.1** just like work in other API version.

The link for solution library is [Click Here For MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

Add this library by adding below line in **dependencies{...}** of `build.gradle`(app) file.

```
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.1'
```

Then implement below code as per need:-

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) myContext;
    final DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    //To do your task here
                }
            },
            mYear,
            mMonth,
            mDay
    );
    dpd.setVersion(DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_2);
    dpd.setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    dpd.show(mainActivity.getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed in comments, there is no really perfect solution for this buggy calendar(on Android 5.0 you can select an invalid date and on some Samsung devices a strange behaviour was present: pressing back button was actually selecting a date and others that I don't really remember). However, I fixed the problem when you can select an invalid date by checking its validity and displaying a `Toast` in case of failure. This will NOT STOP the user from actually selecting an invalid date, but rather force the user to select a valid date in order to continue using the app.

```
   DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mOnDateSetListener, year, month, day) {
        private boolean allowClose = false;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            allowClose = true;
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            allowClose = true;
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE && !validate()) {
                allowClose = false;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.invalid_date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (allowClose) {
                super.onClick(dialog, which);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dismiss() {
            if (allowClose) {
                super.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
```

By using this, you make sure that if the user select an invalid date, you will give him a proper warning message and stop the calendar from closing when you press the `Ok` button. The `validate` function should be created to fit your needs, but I think that what I have will do just fine:

```
private boolean validate() {
    if (this.getDialog() instanceof DatePickerDialog) {
        DatePicker datePicker = ((DatePickerDialog) this.getDialog()).getDatePicker();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        boolean valid = false;
        Calendar minCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        minCalendar.setTimeInMillis(datePicker.getMinDate());
        Calendar maxCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        maxCalendar.setTimeInMillis(datePicker.getMaxDate());
        if (DateUtils.in(calendar.getTime(), minCalendar.getTime(), maxCalendar.getTime())) {
            valid = true;
        }
        return valid;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As a final word, I don't guarantee that this is the best solution, but I had used it and didn't received any complains from users.

Comment: Thanks for toast suggestion. I know and have did that already. Need solution if possible not other ways to match requirement.

Comment: Maybe you can achive what you want by subclassing the DatePicker, but I have to investigate this further. I will let this here until I have some time to try the subclassing version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Calender Instance and use it as maxDate. Please refer line added in your code below.

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(myContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    }
}, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

Calendar maxCal = Calendar.getInstance();

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxCal.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Not working.. Can you please check it at your side this is working for lollipop or not?

Comment: Yes its working for lollipop. Already checked. You still able to select date greater than today with this code?

Comment: Yes, I am able to select greater than today. And I have real device with lollipop 5.0.1.